# How to ingress stream data with Azure Data Exploere SDK

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

We are needing to write some software, that receives events one at a time, and we need to ingress them into ADX.  We are struggling to understand how the Kusto Client is meant to be utilized.

```
public void SaveEvent(Object event)
{

 var _kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(Uri).WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
            applicationClientId: "{}",
            applicationKey: "{}",
            authority: TenantId);

using var ingestClient = KustoIngestFactory.CreateQueuedIngestClient(_kcsb);

//// Create your custom implementation of IRetryPolicy, which will affect how the ingest client handles retrying on transient failures
IRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new NoRetry();
//// This line sets the retry policy on the ingest client that will be enforced on every ingest call from here on
        
((IKustoQueuedIngestClient)ingestClient).QueueOptions.QueueRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = retryPolicy;

var ingestProperties = new KustoIngestionProperties(DatabaseName, TableName)
        {
            Format = DataSourceFormat.json,
            IngestionMapping = new IngestionMapping { IngestionMappingKind = Kusto.Data.Ingestion.IngestionMappingKind.Json, IngestionMappingReference = MappingName }
        };

 // Build the stream

 var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream: stream, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, bufferSize: 4096, leaveOpen: true);
        using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
        packet.Id = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, event);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       
// Tell the client to ingest this
await ingestClient.IngestFromStreamAsync(data, ingestProperties);

}
```

Now I have several concerns with this.  We are calling this function 300 to 500 times a second. I believe the custom client has built in batching,  but do we not then need to use a singleton instance of the custom client?

Next thing is that I am creating a steam per event and then calling ingerss. This feels wrong? is there no way I can setup the custom client etc, and then just enqueue each event into the custom client as we receiver them?

Comment: have you considered using Event Hub in the middle? I.e. your client app just writes into Event Hub and then you have ADX ingest server-side from Event Hub

Comment: I have looked into that, but I feel it is a sort of unnecessary step, adding cost, complexity and another point of failure. To my limit knowledge, the SDK basically write to azure queue storage first then it tells ADZ to ingress it from there. Which seemed pretty nice & efficent.